# How can i detect remote images in a document?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a document loaded. If the document has remote images in it, i want to print a specific message.

I am struggling to do it. I could use javascript and access to document.images object. But still I need to know if there is an image in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could simply iterate over the images, get the source and then check if it has the same hostname as the current page

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (const img of images) {
  const imageLocation = img.src;
  if (imageLocation.indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1) {
    console.log(imageLocation);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to find all dom items with `<img>` tag, then check if these items start with http:// or https:// and don't contains your current domain

Example with jQuery:

```
$('img').each(function(){
   var src= $(this).attr("src");
   if(!src.contains("YOUR_DOMAIN") && (src.startsWith("https://") || src.startsWith("http://"))) {
     alert("not my domain in image URL");
   }
});
```